# Use column value as column name to create a cross-tab

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a long table with groups of rows that look like this. Essentially, I'd like to use the value stored in `v1` to rename `v1_hasvalue`, and likewise for `v2`.

```
v1 <- rep(c("varA"), 4)
v2 <- rep(c("varB"), 4)
v1_hasvalue <- c(1,1,0,0)
v2_hasvalue <- c(1,0,1,0)
n <- c(100, 20, 30, 40)

have <- data.frame(v1, v2, v1_hasvalue, v2_hasvalue, n)
```

How can I go from this:

```
  v1 v2 v1_hasvalue v2_hasvalue   n
1  A  B           1           1 100
2  A  B           1           0  20
3  A  B           0           1  30
4  A  B           0           0  40
```

to this:

```
  varA varB   n
1    1    1 100
2    1    0  20
3    0    1  30
4    0    0  40
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may rename the columns as

```
names(have)[3:4] <- unlist(have[1, 1:2])
have <- have[-(1:2)]
```

-output

```
> have
  varA varB   n
1    1    1 100
2    1    0  20
3    0    1  30
4    0    0  40
```

Comment: Thank you so much @akrun for your helpful input.